# With AWS Copilot how to configure AWS ALB to have 2 path rules to forward requests to the same target group/ Fargate service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-copilot

With AWS Copilot, is it possible to configure AWS ALB rules to have multiple rules with different paths to  forward to same target group i.e. have multiple paths configured for a Copilot service?

Something like following?

```
http:
  - path: "path1"
  - path: "path2"
```

Is additional rules the way to go? The [doc](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/lb-web-service/#http-additional-rules) is not clear for me! Please guide.

And also is there a way to **configure the default ALB rule with Copilot**?